# How to use regex ?: operator and get the right group in my case?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match `field[123][33]["code"]` where `["code"]` is optional.

So I made this regex `/field\[(\d*)\]\[(\d*)\]((?:\[")(.+)(?:"\]))?/g` that is doing fine.

The problem is that it's coming in 4 groups `123`, `33`, `["code"]` and `code` but I only want 3 groups `123`, `33`, `code`. Is it possible?

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/jRAQUc/2) is a test example.

Comment: `field\[(\d*)\]\[(\d*)\](?:\["([^\][]+)"\])?`? In other words, `(?:<CONTEXT>(<WHAT_YOU_NEED_TO_GET>)<CONTEXT>)?`

Comment: you can simply add `?:` to the enclosing `()`: `field\[(\d*)\]\[(\d*)\](?:(?:\[")(.+)(?:"\]))?`

Comment: thanks, that helped alot